# Java Date to String parsing / validation help needed

Tags: java, string, validation, parsing, date

I'm having trouble changing my date field in java to a string.  It works in my output toString but the validation piece doesn't recognize.  What is wrong with my code?  I cannot have users posting anything but a true "M/d/yyyy" date but my validation isn't working.  Thoughts?

I've posted the start date code below, the "end date" code is the same but thought you should know it is present.

Many thanks in advance.

```
        String stringStartDate = this.txtStartDate.getText();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
        Date pStartDate = null;

        if (stringStartDate.length() > 0)
        {
            try {
                pStartDate = formatter.parse(stringStartDate);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

          if (pStartDate == null)
          {
            this.textArea.setText(this.textArea.getText() + "\n"
              + "Error! Please enter a valid start date in the format M/d/yyyy (e.g. 1/2/2015)!");
            return;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          this.textArea.setText(this.textArea.getText() + "\n"
            + "Error! Please enter a valid start date in the format M/d/yyyy (e.g. 1/2/2015)!");
          return;
        }
```

Here is my toString()... this is working perfectly.

```
    @Override 
    public String toString(){
    return "Pay Period Start Date = " +        simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear.format(this.pStartDate) + "\n" 
            + "Pay Period End Date = " + simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear.format(this.pEndDate) + "\n";

    }
```

From the comments and my own trial and error I've change a few things around but now neither work.  What is the deal?

```
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
        String stringStartDate = simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear.format(this.txtStartDate.getText());
        Date pStartDate = null;

        if (stringStartDate.length() > 0)
        {
            try {
                pStartDate = simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear.parse(stringStartDate);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

          if (pStartDate == null)
          {
            this.textArea.setText(this.textArea.getText() + "\n"
              + "Error! Please enter a valid start date in the format M/d/yyyy (e.g. 1/2/2015)!");
            return;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          this.textArea.setText(this.textArea.getText() + "\n"
            + "Error! Please enter a valid start date in the format M/d/yyyy (e.g. 1/2/2015)!");
          return;
        }
```

Comment: I notice the one that works uses `simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear` while the one that doesn't uses `formatter`. Are the formats the same for both? Have you validated the input you're trying to parse? Have you stepped into the code with a debugger?

Comment: Have you considered using something [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) instead?  They can perform the validation automatically or you (assume you're using Swing)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch when I change to the simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear it seems to get worse.  Thoguhts?  I've done the step over step debugger but to no avail.

Comment: @MadProgrammer a JSpinner is out of the question.  I haven't worked for JFormattedTextFields much but am going to start looking into them if I can't get this to work.  I feel like the answer is right in front of me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format a `String` ...

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
String stringStartDate = simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear.format(field.getText());
```

which simply doesn't make sense.  You want to `parse` the `String` value to a `Date`

The first thing you want to do is `parse` the `String` value to a `Date`, this will check to see if the `String` is in the correct format.  Once you've done that, you want to check to see if the formatted version of the parsed `Date` is equal to the text in the field, to see if the date is actually valid...

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
try {
    Date date = simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear.parse(field.getText());

    if (date != null) {

        String formatted = simpleDateFormatMonthDayYear.format(date);
        if (!formatted.equals(field.getText())) {

            System.out.println("Date is not valid");

        }

    } else {

        System.out.println("Error! Please enter a valid start date in the format M/d/yyyy (e.g. 1/2/2015)!");

    }
} catch (ParseException exp) {

    System.out.println("Error! Please enter a valid start date in the format M/d/yyyy (e.g. 1/2/2015)!");

}
```

But I'd just use `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField` as these can auto valid the text themselves, but that's just me (or `JXDatePicker` from SwingLabs SwingX library, because I'm just that lazy)

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer.  I changed mine to match yours and it appears to be working.  This seems good enough to get by but I'm going to start diving into JXDatePicker... that looks more ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us what tests the method is failing on. My usual method of finding errors in code like this is to test, find a test input that fails, step through it with a debugger and see where it is failing.

But, here is a hint. I note that you are using "M/d/yyyy" for a format. This is problematic because some months have two digits, and some days have two digits. Why not use "MM/dd/YYYY"?

Comment: *"Why not use "MM/dd/YYYY""* - Because the format is not nearly as important when parsing a `String` to the `Date` and the parser will take into account multiple digits where a single format key is present and secondly, `Y` is the week in the year, not the year...